# How to query the Google Ads API for recently disabled campaigns

Tags: java, api, google-ads-api

Is it even possible to query for recently disabled campaigns, without any prior tracking of the state and changes?

E.g. a list of campaign which were disabled within the last 3 days.

Is it possible with the AdWords API or the new Google Ads Beta API?

Answer (score 1):

In the api you can query for removed campaigns but you can't get the date of when they were removed.

My suggestion would be to query campaigns using the reporting api that have;

- Status: Removed
- Date: Greater Than Last 3 Days
- Impressions: Greater Than 0

This is the closest i think you will get to what you need.